# unable to run Jenkins.war on JBOSS AS 7.1

Tags: jenkins, jboss

I'm trying to test Jenkins deployment on my JBOSS AS 7.1. After deployment (from JBOSS Web Console), i cannot enable jenkins due to follow error:

[image: error]

Please help me to fix that,
Thanks

Comment: Please include the textual content of the error in your question.

Comment: Unexpected HTTP response: 500

Request
{
    "address" => [("deployment" => "jenkins.war")],
    "operation" => "deploy"
}

Response

Internal Server Error
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./jenkins" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./jenkins: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"}},
    "rolled-back" => true
}